# How to "listen" to current process exit with native C++ in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, signals

My application starts a process and I need it to automatically close when the application closes. The application can be closed by the Task Manager, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or some other standard close operation.

I've tried using:

- `signal(SIGTERM, callback)` from `signal.h`
- `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(callback, TRUE)` from `windows.h`
- `atexit(callback)` from `stdlib.h`

But none of them did the job.

## Using signal

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
void onExit(int sig) {
    std::cout << "sig(" << sig << ")" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, onExit);
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
}
```

## Using SetConsoleCtrlHandler

I've copied the code from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/registering-a-control-handler-function)

## Using atexit

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void onExit(void) {
    std::cout << "sig(" << ")" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    atexit(onExit);
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
}
```

None of the above solution called the callback when I terminated the application from the Task Manager nor the close button.

What should I do?

Comment: Programs with a "main" don't have a close button - they are console applications.

Comment: I was talking about `cmd.exe` 'close' button

Comment: No code in your application will run when you terminate it from Task Manager using "End Process" -- that calls `TerminateProcess` and the target process immediately stops running code.  For the close 'X' and Task Manager End Task, `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` does work.  But you need more than just a link to an MSDN example to help us help you.

Comment: @BenVoigt, console clients other than the effective owner can only be killed gracefully by killing the owner. In this case, each process has up to 5 seconds to handle the close event before the session server (csrss.exe) terminates it. In particular, gracefully killing a process by sending `WM_CLOSE` to its console window requires associating the window back to the process ID. The console selects one client thread/process as the effective owner of the window, which is stored as window data to special case `GetWindowThreadProcessId`. This is initially the process that allocates the console.